# How to find items that are not on the right side of a OneToOneField?

Tags: python, django

I have these two models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    plate = models.OneToOneField(Plate, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Plate(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
```

As you can see, there can only be one `Plate` connected to a `Location`. But how to find all `Plate`s, that are not assigned to a `Location` ?

I can count them like this:

```
models.Plate.objects.count() - models.Location.objects.filter(plate__isnull=False).count()
```

but I need a list of `Plate`s, not just a number. I tried to search online and in the docs, but I actually have no idea what to search for. And I do not see how I could do this with `Q` objects or the `filter` method.

Comment: What about `models.Plate.objects.filter(location__isnull=True)`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: @yofee thanks, it was that simple.